# IORedis or (node_redis) callback not firing after calling custom Redis commands/modules

Tags: node.js, websocket, redis, node-redis, ioredis

When using redis client (ioredis or node_redis) inside websocket's message event in a nodejs app, the callback for any command is not immediately fired. (the operation does take place on redis server though)

What is strange is that the callback for the first command will fire after i sent a second message, and the callback for the second will fire after i send a third.

```
wss.on('connection', (socket, request) => {

     socket.on('message', (data) => {

      console.log("will send test command")
      this.pubClient.hset("test10", "f1","v1", (err,value) => {
          //callback not firing first time
          console.log("test command reply received")
       })

    })

}
```

the redis command is working as expected though in other parts of the app and even when inside the on connection directly like below.

```
wss.on('connection', (socket, request) => {

    console.log("will send test command")
    this.pubClient.hset("test10", "f1","v1", (err,value) => {
        //callback fires
        console.log("test command reply received")
    })

    socket.on('message', (data) => {})
}
```

**UPDATE:**

I had this all wrong. The reason for the weird callback behavior is the result of one my custom Redis modules not returning a reply. 
And this seems to have caused all callbacks after this call to seem to have some kind of a one step delay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this all wrong. The reason for the weird callback behavior is the result of one my custom Redis modules not returning a reply. And this seems to have caused all callbacks after this call to seem to have some kind of a one step delay.